# PHP: newbie question - something like with/end with in php?

Tags: php, asp-classic

is there something like with/end with (like in asp) for php?
especially for class objects it would be nice - asp syntax is like:

```
with myWeb
    .init "myweb"
    response.write .html  
end with
```

thanks

Comment: it may help if you could explain what the with/end structure does.

Comment: what does with/end do, then i might be able to help :-D

Comment: @jW and @maniator, basically you say "with object"  and then instead of having to type `$obj->variable = "something"` it would be `->variable = "something"` as long as it was within the "with" block.

Comment: not sure but i think end is like die and end triggers the with object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such thing in PHP : you have to write the full name of classes / objects / variables / whatever when you want to use them.

Comment: Kudos to PHP for that! One of the worst features of VB in my opinion. :/

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK.

Do you really find this syntax useful ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is an [alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

not sure im right but tryed my best to translate your example :/

```
<?php function write_block(){
echo '.html';
}

die(write_block());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you wanted, but you can do something similar with PHP references:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $bar1 = 1;
    public $bar2 = 2;
    public $bar3 = 3;
}

class B {
    public $foo;
}

class C {
    public $foobar;
}

$myC = new C;
$myC->foobar = new B;
$myC->foobar->foo = new A;

print $myC->foobar->foo->bar1;
print $myC->foobar->foo->bar2;
print $myC->foobar->foo->bar3;

//Simpler with 'With...End With syntax:
//which might look something like:
//
// with ($myC->foobar->foo)         //Note this is not valid PHP
// {
//      print ->bar1;           //Note this is not valid PHP
//      print ->bar2;           //Note this is not valid PHP
//      print ->bar3;           //Note this is not valid PHP
// }
//
//Fortunately, you can sort of do this using an object reference:
//

$obj =& $myC->foobar->foo;
    print $obj->bar1;
    print $obj->bar2;
    print $obj->bar3;

unset ($obj);
?>
```

Comment: The advantage of this method is that you don't need to worry about nesting your "with" statements, as you just use simplified named objects to refer to the bit you want.